# How to send mails with Flask-Mail in non-route scripts

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I have a Flask server.
In `route.py` I have this:

```
from flask_mail import Mail

app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'source@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password.'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail= Mail(app)
```

I want to send mail in a function situated in another script using `flask_mail.Message()` and `mail.send`, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this example:

**email.py**

```
from flask_mail import Message
from app import mail

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):

msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
msg.body = text_body
msg.html = html_body
mail.send(msg)
```

source: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support

(Great tutorial on flask in general)

Comment: Thanks for answer but still have the problem. It does not give me any error but the email is not sent. Instead, if I use the mail in main script of the app (where there are all API) it works.

Comment: oh, so you want to use the flask email function outside of flask itself? If that's the case i would recommend using smtplib and handle the whole email process on its own